# jBoss 4.2.3 : what is the order of jar loading inside \server\default\lib

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

In jboss 4.2.3 what's the order it uses to load the *.jar inside the "server\default\lib" folder?

I mean, inside server\default\lib I have: a.jar b.jar z.jar. What's the order jboss is gonna load them? What affects the ordering jboss uses?

I'm having a weird IllegalAccessError during jboss startup that only happens on 1 environment (Oracle enterprise linux 6.3, 64bits), and works fine on other 5 environments (with the same OS, different OS's, different jdk versions, etc. JDK 1.6.0_45-b06. I think this ordering may have something to do with my problem so that's the root cause of my question.

Comment: What's the IllegalAccessError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it follows File.list ordering:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list()